# Win+PrtSc shortcut not taking screenshot

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, print-screen

A while ago I deleted my default "Screenshots" folder in my Windows 10 "Pictures" folder. This is the folder where my <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> screenshots used to get saved.

I realized my mistake and created a folder with the same name but now the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> doesn't work anymore. The screen goes dark (the standard screenshot procedure) for a second, but the actual picture doesn't get taken and stored to the location.

Can I somehow restore the default functionality to take a screenshot?

P.S. I know I can just use <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and paste it in paint and create a file or use SNIP tool but the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> did all this for me in just a second.

Comment: Deleting the screenshot folder won’t make a difference, instead delete the one which you created and restart the pc, windows will automatically create a folder and then try the shortcut to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative ways:

<kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

You can also use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or the new Screen snip button in the Action Center) to capture a screenshot with Snip & Sketch. Your screen will dim and you'll see Snip & Sketch's small menu at the top of your screen that will let you choose with type of screenshot you want to capture.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>

To take a quick screenshot of the active window, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. This will snap your currently active window and copy the screenshot to the clipboard. You'll need to open the shot in an image editor to save it.

Comment: Windows+Shift+S or Alt+PrintScreen do different things than Windows+PrintScreen

Answer (score 0):

You have (re)moved something from your screenshots folder which altered the default location. Try resetting it from the [properties](https://www.howtogeek.com/139350/change-the-location-of-the-default-screenshot-folder-in-windows-8/) of the usual folder (recreate that if needed):

[image: Screenshot Properties in Windows 10]

If that doesn't work, use [Registry Editor](https://windowsreport.com/screenshots-windows-10/) to set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` key `{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}` to `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots` or run this scary-looking `fix_screenshots_folder.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,\
  50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,50,00,69,00,63,00,74,\
  00,75,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,73,00,\
  68,00,6f,00,74,00,73,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 0):

> The screen goes dark (the standard screenshot procedure) for a second, but the actual picture doesn't get taken and stored...

The screen dimming makes me think the picture was taken, just not stored in the location you expected. Im my frequent use of `WinKey`+`PrtScn,` the file is not only saved to my `ScreenShots` folder, but also appears in the `Recent Files` section of **Quick Access** (naturally, the feture has to be turned on).

> Screenshots when I get a better connectioin
> [image]

[image]

- In the **Explorer** *Address bar* or a **Run** dialog, you can type:

**`shell:ScreenShots`**

[image]
to open the locaatin the system has determined to be the Screenshots location, which can be afftected by several factors:

- **System Defaults**:  `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions`
- **OneDrive Settings**:
- **Explicit Re-direction**: via the `Location` tab in the **Screenshots** folder's  **Properties** dialog (if you don't see a `LOcation` tab in the dialog, it's not the designated folder). Explicit re-direction creates a registry value that doesn't exist in a new account: `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}` which defines the folder's file system location.
- **Inherited Re-direction**: The folder is in a non-default location because its default *ParentFolder*, `shell:My Pictures` ( FDID: `{33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}` ), has been re-directed.

If `shell:screenshots` fails, it is most likely being re-directed to a non-existent location. Create the target folder or eliminate the invalid re-direction based on your original intentions.